# How to reduce the apk size while using MAPBOX in android

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm using map box SDK on my android application. Total apk size will be 24MB.

How to reduce that size?

Please give solutions

```
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Comment: try to "shrinkResources true"

Comment: **Reducing apk size** Refer [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/how-i-decreased-my-app-size-to-70-using-apk-analyser-4a6f79512072) link

Comment: Thanks a lot.That link reduced my apk size.

Answer (score 0):

for reducing the Apk size you need to focus on to many things like.

assets
res
lib
etc
Check these :
-Rmove unused resources
-support for specific densities
-reuse resources
- use aaptOptions{
  cruncherEnable=false
}
- use shrinkResouces true I'm build.gradle

Also use progard

For more info look this
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html

Answer (score 0):

Besides using tools as proguard mentioned by others. You can optimise for the different ABI's that the library supports by using APK split. By default the Mapbox SDK includes support for:

- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- arm64-v8a
- x86
- x86-64
- mips

You can use ABI split as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-abi-split) to build separate APKs for each ABI or just include support for specific ABIs. More information about ABIs in general [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html).